# Can't recognize _Nonnull when building adb with g++

Tags: android, c++, g++, adb, non-nullable

I am trying to build adb from the [AOSP android 7.1.2 source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/tree/master/adb) and compiling it with g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609, by slowly adding includes and libraries based on the ***Android.mk*** and fixing the compiler complaints as I go. So far I got to the command below but I'm not certain how to solve the error below:

```
adb-1.0.36/system/core$ g++ -o ./adb/adb_client{,.cpp} -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wvla -DADB_REVISION='1.0.36' -std=c++14 -I./base/include/ -I./include -lrt -ldl -lpthread -fvisibility=hidden
In file included from ./adb/adb_client.cpp:20:0:
./adb/adb_client.h:28:67: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘error’
 int adb_connect(const std::string& service, std::string* _Nonnull error);
                                                               ^
./adb/adb_client.h:29:68: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘error’
 int _adb_connect(const std::string& service, std::string* _Nonnull error);
                                                                ^
./adb/adb_client.h:37:66: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘result’
 bool adb_query(const std::string& service, std::string* _Nonnull result,
                                                              ^
./adb/adb_client.h:41:66: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘serial’
 void adb_set_transport(TransportType type, const char* _Nullable serial);
                                                              ^
./adb/adb_client.h:44:49: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘type’
 void adb_get_transport(TransportType* _Nullable type, const char* _Nullable* _Nullable serial);
                                             ^
./adb/adb_client.h:50:45: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘hostname’
 void adb_set_tcp_name(const char* _Nullable hostname);
                                         ^
./adb/adb_client.h:55:61: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
 int adb_send_emulator_command(int argc, const char* _Nonnull* _Nonnull argv,
                                                         ^
./adb/adb_client.h:60:47: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘error’
 bool adb_status(int fd, std::string* _Nonnull error);
                                           ^
./adb/adb_client.h:63:54: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘command’
 std::string format_host_command(const char* _Nonnull command, TransportType type,
                                                  ^
./adb/adb_client.h:67:47: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘feature_set’
 bool adb_get_feature_set(FeatureSet* _Nonnull feature_set, std::string* _Nonnull error);
                                           ^
```

It seems like **_Nonnull** and **_Nullable** are defined in the ***./adb/sysdeps.h***

```
58 // Clang-only nullability specifiers
57 #define _Nonnull
59 #define _Nullable
```

Seems like AOSP 7.1.2 is comes with gcc 4.8.
Also, I noticed that the **-Wexit-time-destructors** doesn't seem to be part of g++ I'm using nor is **-compatibility_version**

```
ltecoe@ltecoe:~/imx6solox-yocto-bsp/sources/meta-harris-tools/recipes-connectivity/adb/adb-1.0.36/system/core$ g++ -o ./adb/adb_client{,.cpp} -compatibility_version -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wvla -DADB_REVISION='1.0.36' -std=c++14 -Wexit-time-destructors -I./base/include/ -I./include -lrt -ldl -lpthread
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-compatibility_version’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wexit-time-destructors’
```

Answer (score 1):

`_Nonnull` and `_Nullable` are [Clang's private keywords](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nullability-attributes). That 2 lines of declarations are not executed because of the condition `#ifdef _WIN32`.

So in order to compile it using `g++` on Linux, put those 2 declarations to other places where they come into effect globally.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I will give this a try in the near future and let you know.

Comment: Near future was too far (XD), but I'll confirm ahah. Worked! Thank you!